# How to find the corresponding 2D Cartesian coordinates from 3D ellipsoid?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres, elliptic-operators

I want to implement trilateration algorithm in short distance (maximum 50 meters), so instead of calculating intersections among spheres, I can roughly deal with it as finding intersections among circles on a plain. And I can get the `(lat,lon)` from my gps and convert it into 3D Cartesian coordinates.(I'm projecting (lat,lon) to WGS84) I haven't played with geometry for a while, so my questions is, how to convert the 3D Cartesian coordinates on a sphere to 2D Cartesian coordinates on a circle?

Comment: Normally projecting coordinates over WGS84 you obtain eastings and northings.
Just use those values as x and y coordinates on the cartesian plane.

Comment: @N74, and then I can simply calculate the intersections among circles?

Comment: Yes, and then convert back, if you need, the easting and northing of the intersection in coordinates. That will work good enough for distances under 100km.

Comment: Well, it's good to know the accuracy and use case.

Comment: @N74, luckily I've already worked out the solution to find the intersections among spheres. Convert it to 2D plain will add complexity to my steps. It's still a good point to know. I'll try it when I have time and give an answer.

Comment: For distances so short as yours I normally pick one of the known points as the origin and work on $\Delta lat$ and $\Delta lon$ to find $y=\Delta lon R_{Earth}$ and $x=\Delta lat \cos(lat_0) R_{Earth}$. Accuracy is a little worst, but calculations are far easier.

Comment: Yep, that's a trade off. For my industrial need, accuracy is more important. Anyway, thanks for your brief help.

Comment: Take care and avoid measuring mountains with calipers. A 3D solution is needed for greater distances but gives unuseful digits of resolution for a 50m problem: if the accuracy of the position of the beacons is greater than few millimeters you'll find no enhancement in the final accuracy.

Comment: For a distance of $50$m on same see level on earth, the correction to coordinates due to non-linearity is of the order $\frac{50^2}{6.371 \times 01^7}$m $ \sim 0.04$mm. The accuracy of GPS coordinate w/ all sort of enhancement is of the order of a few mm. There is no need to worry about the non-linearity for such short distances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to the stated question; rather, this is a how-to for obtaining 2D or 3D coordinates via trilateration with quite simple math.

Although not very useful for GPS location data (due to jitter etc. at this scale), this could be used with e.g. ultrasonic transducers with timing info provided via wired or radio-frequency connection, using the delay between the two to detect the distance to each.

If you have three locators, and know the delay/distance between one pair, and between each to current location, you can obtain 2D or 3D coordinates (based on the plane defined by the locators) with just basic math as shown below. This is lightweight enough to do even on a weak microcontroller.

---

Trilateration is simple even in 3D, if you do the majority of the calculations in the plane defined by your three control points. You can trivially obtain the 2D coordinates with respect to that plane. To obtain the 3D coordinates, you additionally solve the distance to the plane, and project the obtained coordinates back to the original coordinate system.

(A long time ago I contributed the projection method (most of "preliminary computations") to the Wikipedia [Trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) article; before that, it used trigonometric functions to rotate and manipulate the coordinate system. If you see trilateration documentation that uses any trigonometric functions like $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$, or their inverses (arcus functions), don't rely on it; it is a ridiculously complicated way to do it.)

Let's assume you have three known points, $\vec{P}_1$, $\vec{P}_2$, and $\vec{P}_3$, whose coordinates (and distances to) are known.

First, we move to an easier coordinate system, with $z=0$ on the plane of the known points, origin at $\vec{P}_1$, and $x$ axis towards $\vec{P}_2$. $y$ axis will be perpendicular to $x$ of course, and increases to the side $\vec{P}_3$ is on. To get a normal Cartesian coordinate system ($x$ increasing right and $y$ up), assign the three known points in counterclockwise order.

The distance between $\vec{P}_1$ and $\vec{P}_2$ is $d$. The new $y$ axis increases towards $\vec{P}_3$, which will be at $(i,j)$ in the new coordinates.  Note that the scale is the same in both old and new coordinates; only the origin and orientation differs.
$$d = \left\lVert \vec{P}_2 - \vec{P}_1 \right\rVert$$
$$\hat{e}_x = \frac{ \vec{P}_2 - \vec{P}_1 }{ d }$$
$$i = \hat{e}_x \cdot \left ( \vec{P}_3 - \vec{P}_1 \right )$$
$$\hat{e}_y = \frac{ \vec{P}_3 - \vec{P}_1 - i \hat{e}_x }{ \left\lVert \vec{P}_3 - \vec{P}_1 - i \hat{e}_x \right\rVert }$$
$$j = \hat{e}_y \cdot \left ( \vec{P}_3 - \vec{P}_1 \right )$$

The direction perpendicular to the plane formed by the three known points in the original coordinate system is $\hat{e}_z = \hat{e}_x \times \hat{e}_y$.

Note that if $j = 0$, the three known points $\vec{P}_1$, $\vec{P}_2$, and $\vec{P}_3$ are collinear, and are not a suitable triplet for trilateration.

If we know the distances to the three known points, say $r_1$, $r_2$, and $r_3$, we can calculate the coordinates in the new coordinate system trivially. Note that $r_1$, $r_2$, and $r_3$ are in new coordinate system units, i.e. the distance between $\vec{P}_1$ and $\vec{P}_2$ is $1$. If you instead have direct propagation times $t_1$, $t_2$, and $t_3$, and you know that the propagation time from $\vec{P}_1$ to $\vec{P}_2$ is $\tau$, then
$$r_1 = \frac{t_1}{\tau}, \; r_2 = \frac{t_2}{\tau}, \; r_3 = \frac{t_3}{\tau}$$ 
$$\begin{cases}
x = \frac{r_1^2 - r_2^2 + d^2}{2 d} \\
y = \frac{r_1^2 - r_3^2 + i^2 + j^2}{2 j} \\
z = \pm\sqrt{r_1^2 - x^2 - y^2}
\end{cases}$$
If you are only interested in the planar coordinates, in the plane formed by the three known points, just ignore the $z$ coordinate here.

Also remember that in these new coordinates, $\vec{P}_1$ is at $(0,0,0)$, $\vec{P}_2$ is at $(d,0,0)$, and $\vec{P}_3$ is at $(i,j,0)$. This is very useful for planar mapping.

If you want to map the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ to the original coordinates, use
$$\vec{p} = \vec{P}_1 + x \hat{e}_x + y \hat{e}_y + z \hat{e}_z$$

Note that you only need basic math operations to implement all the above: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and square root.